# Smoothing out the edges of Shrinkwrapped and tilted cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I have a cylinder that I want to wrap around the handle, but the edges have these huge steps to them, is there any way I can smooth them out? I tried subdividing it further, but it didn't help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your objects? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=nNexg5da" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nNexg5da/) @moonboots Here is the file containing the objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handle is not high-poly enough, if you subdivide it with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier you'll have a better result:

[image]

Comment: This has done the trick exactly, thank you for your help. I have a an extra question, if you don't mind. How did you make it so the edges of the handle, don't look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/f3xp4CS) (this is after applying Subdivision modifier with all the numbers exactly like yours)? I used SHIFT+E to sharpen the edges ([link](https://imgur.com/a/Z7ff7lv)), and it looked good, but not quite like yours, so I was just curious as to what you did there.

Comment: I've beveled the edge (Ctrl B and choose the number of segments in the Operator Box)